# Regex for scraping City and State out of bloated description

Tags: python, regex

You can see description here http://www.mdh.org/sites/www/healthapp/jobs/View.aspx?id=10

> MDH Human Resources
>
> 525 E. Grant St.
>
> Macomb, IL  61455
>
> T:  309-836-1577
>
> F:  309-836-1677

The page has this address and I want to extract City and State using regex. In this case it's Macomb and IL.

For a moment I used following regex but it did not work where description contain more than one similar patterns.

```
(\w+),\s+(\w{2})\s+\d+
```

How can I write regex which tells to first extract these address lines and then the line which has this pattern?

Comment: which programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^([A-Z][A-Za-z\s]*),\s+([A-Z]{2})\s+\d{5}$
```

which I think would be good enough to keep noise away. The downside is that it could potentially avoid what you desire. In that case, you may want to iterate through the page using a less strong regular expression like yours. Anyway, you can't achieve perfection using regex.

It works with [Javascript](http://rubular.com/r/ZoMBOb4mrE). Adjust the syntax to meet the need of Python.